# Add EFS volume to ECS for persistent mongodb data

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, mern, persistent-volumes

I believe this requirement seems pretty straight forward for anyone trying to host their Tier3 i.e. database in a container.

I have MVP 3x Tier MERN app using -

- 1x Container instance
- 3x ECS services (Frontend, Backend and Database)
- 3x Tasks (1x running task per service)
- The Database Task (mongodb) has its task definition updated to use EFS and have tested stopping the task and re-starting a new one for data persistence.

Question - How to ensure auto mount of EFS volume on the ECS container host (SPOT instance). If ECS leverages cloud formation template under the covers, do I need to update or modify this template to gain this persistent efs volume auto mounted on all container ec2 instances? I have come across various articles talking about a script in the ec2 launch config but I don't see any launch config created by ECS / cloud formation.

What is the easiest and simplest way to achieve something as trivial as persistent efs volume across my container host instances. Am guessing task definition alone doesn't solve this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I think below steps achieved persistence for the db task using efs -

1. Updated task definition for the database container to use EFS.
2. Mounted the EFS vol on container instance

sudo mount -t efs -o tls fs-:/ /database/data
The above mount command did not add any entries within the /etc/fstab but still seems to be persistent on the new ECS SPOT instance.

Comment: You would just configure the EFS volume mount in the ECS task definition. There is no need to run `sudo mount ...` commands, as the ECS service will do that for you.

Comment: Thanks @MarkB, I just got confused when I saw too many blogs on cloud formation and / or ec2 launch config examples. Maybe, AWS added this feature later..